# JavaFX - Sorting Algorithms - BarChart not updating

Tags: java, sorting, user-interface, javafx

Here is a hope that someone might be able to help me.
I have to work on a project for sorting algorithms and have had to develop an application which uses an interface, so that a sorted list is updated on the Console, a ListView and this "Bargraph" (a subclass of BarChart).

The project has the following classes:

GUI.class (GUI + Controller)

Sorting.class (Fill array and sorting algorithms)

Display.class (Interface --> update(...))

Console.class (Displays to Console)

Listbox.class (Extended ListView with update(...))

Bargraph.class (Extended BarChart with update(...))

The project works completely, the only problem I have is when I call the method update(...) from the corresponding method "swap" in Sorting.class.

For a worst case bubble sort with many swaps, the display only shows the beginning and the end. No redrawing of the BarChart is performed until the end.

Is there a way to implement this by using an implementation or would I have to change a lot more?

Many thanks in advance! :)

```
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;


/**
 *
 * Beschreibung
 *
 * @version 1.0 vom 13.01.2018
 * @author 
 */

public class Bargraph extends BarChart implements Display {


  private int[] numlist;


  public Bargraph(CategoryAxis xAxis, NumberAxis yAxis)
  {
    super(xAxis, yAxis);
  }


  private void delay() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(200);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void update(int[] numlist) {

    this.numlist=numlist;

    XYChart.Series data = new XYChart.Series();

    this.getData().clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < numlist.length; i++ ) {
      XYChart.Data column = new XYChart.Data<>(String.valueOf(i), numlist[i]);
      data.getData().add(column);
    }
    this.getData().addAll(data);

  }


}
```